# Update textbox from java code (Android, Cordova, HTML5)

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am developing one Android app using Cordova. On the app startup I want to show some dynamic message on the UI which is index.html. How can I show this message from Java code.

index.html

MainActivity.java
How to update the value of text box on index.html ?

In short I want to update some value from my JAVA code not from JavaScript!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it. (less stress)
First you need to attach an event listener to the OnLoad Event of the index.

HTML

```
<body onLoad="showMessage()">
```

JavaScript

```
function showMessage()
{
 alert('Hello Message');
}
```

Now the showMessage() function will be called as soon as the page load is completed. Do note that you can also create your own method for displaying a message instead of using an alert.

You're welcome.

**UPDATE**
This is a simple method for showing a dynamic message (instead of an alert)
I'm only adding this because i'm guessing that you are requesting help with the code also. So here is a super sweet alert box, complete with animations.

First make sure you have the required HTML on the page that will be used to display the message

HTML

```
<div id="Page_Alert" class="Animate_Opacity">
<div id="Page_Alert_Box_Container" class="Box_Container Animate_MarginTop">
<div id="Page_Alert_Title">Alert Preview</div>
<div id="Page_Alert_Content">This is just a preview of what an alert popUp will look like.</div>
<div class="Buttons_Container">
<div class="BTN" onClick="hide_AlertWindow()">OK</div>
<!-- <div class="BTN">CANCEL</div> -->
</div>
</div>
<div class="bg"></div>
</div><!-- End Alert Pop Up -->
```

CSS

```
#Page_Alert{position:absolute; top:0; left:0%; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:-20; opacity:0; overflow:hidden;}
#Page_Alert > .bg{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:BLACK; opacity:.6; z-index:0;}
#Page_Alert > .Box_Container{position:relative; margin:auto; margin-top:-45%; width:80%; min-height:100px; background:WHITE; color:#444; z-index:1;}
#Page_Alert > .Box_Container > #Page_Alert_Title{position:relative; margin:auto; padding-top:18px; width:90%; font-family:OpenSansBold; color:BLACK; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.2em; z-index:1;}
#Page_Alert > .Box_Container > #Page_Alert_Content{position:relative; margin:auto; margin-top:12px; width:90%; background2:RED; font-size:.9em; z-index:1;}
#Page_Alert > .Box_Container > .Buttons_Container{position:relative; margin:auto; margin-top:24px; width:95%; height:40px; background2:RED; z-index:1;}
#Page_Alert > .Box_Container > .Buttons_Container > .BTN{position:relative; margin-right:13px; min-width:3px; height:30px; color:#0286A4; display:block; float:right; text-align:right; font-size:1.15em; font-family:OpenSansSemiBold;}


.Animate_Opacity
{
transition:opacity .5s;
-moz-transition:opacity .5s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:opacity .5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:opacity .5s; /* Opera */
}

.Animate_MarginTop
{
transition:margin-top .4s;
-moz-transition:margin-top .4s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:margin-top .4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:margin-top .4s; /* Opera */
}
```

Now all you do is call this function on page load (or when ever you wish to show an alert.

JavaScript

```
function show_AlertWindow(_title,_content)
{  
  var Page = document.getElementById('Page_Alert');
  var Box = document.getElementById('Page_Alert_Box_Container');
  var Title = document.getElementById('Page_Alert_Title');
  var Content = document.getElementById('Page_Alert_Content');

      Title.innerHTML = _title;
      Content.innerHTML = _content;

      Page.style.zIndex=15; 
      setTimeout(function(){ Page.style.opacity=1; },100);
      setTimeout(function(){ Box.style.marginTop = 45 +'%'; },400);
}

function hide_AlertWindow()
{
  var Page = document.getElementById('Page_Alert');
  var Box = document.getElementById('Page_Alert_Box_Container'); 

      Page.style.opacity=0; 
      setTimeout(function(){ Page.style.zIndex=-1; },200);
      setTimeout(function(){ Box.style.marginTop = -45 +'%'; },300);
}
```

Soooo... if your body tag is like this

```
<body onLoad="show_AlertWindow('Alert Title','Hello message from alert')">
```

You will see a sweet dynamic alert box animate onto the screen.

Your welcome! (I practically did all of the work for you)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply and time! I appreciate! I just update the question. Actually I want to update the UI html5 textbox from my JAVA code not from  JavaScript. I am using Cordova and Android Studio. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Sam or okok. No problem at all, sorry i was not of much help.